# How to make scroll down and scroll up button outside the scroll box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-chrome

Game designer gave me to make the scrollbar with custom up and down button and custom looking scrollbar (not then one natively available from the browser on Windows via Google Chrome)

[image]

I tried as following but how can i remove that native scroller inside the div? and use my own look and feel vertical scrollbar outside the div, which can interact with my existing div?

```css
.FixedHeightContainer {
  height: 250px;
  width:250px; 
  padding:3px; 
  background:#f00;
}
.Content {
  height:224px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<span>UP</span>
<br/>
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
    Game UI sucks<Br/>
    Game UI i hate it, nightmare for programmers<Br/>
    Game UI is hard<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
    Game UI<Br/>
  </div>
</div>

<Br/>
<span>DOWN</span>
```

Comment: overflow:hidden on .content

Comment: and if you want to hide it with overflow:hidden; as @JaromandaX said and still be able to scroll, this post  can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: I've added javascript to UP/DOWN in this http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/4903/

Comment: overflow:hidden worked. But how do i have up, down and scrollbar which looks different but still able to scroll that div?

Comment: make your own scroll bar - you can see how the up/down would work in the fiddle I updated in the previous comment - if you want someone to write the whole scrollbar code for you, it wont be me :)

Comment: Sir, when i tried http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/4903/, its not working to slide up or down.

Comment: It wont work because @JaromandaX is just giving you a hint of how to hide the scroll, if you actually want the scroll to work you have to add another div inside the content and push the scroll bar out of the parent with the overflow:hidden; so it can be hidden, I recommend you to read about custom scrolls and scroll events to solve this question.

Comment: @YumYumYum - click on UP and DOWN (the text) - the code there is just a  proof of concept ... you'll also want a "draggable" item - again, I'm not icanhazcode.com so I'm not writing it for you

Comment: Sir, i haz http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/4904/ where up/down haz working. how can i haz scrollbar which can track the status of where i am ( 0% to 100% vertical range). Can i haz that please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below link. It is a one stop answer for all your queries related to custom scroll bars.

[css-tricks scrollbar](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

**EDIT:** [View Demo](https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)

```
/* For the "inset" look only */
html {
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 30px; 

    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* FAT or SLIM? */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

/* Slider bar */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Button inside the slider  */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```